# New MacBook Pro wobbles

Tags: macbook-pro

I bought a 2011 Macbook Pro, and after unscrewing the cover to install RAM and an SSD, the laptop wobbles while I'm typing. This is really annoying; is there a fix that doesn't involve shipping my laptop away for days or having it replaced with a new one?

Comment: Are you sure you put all the screws on right? Kinda sounds like your SSD is falling out..

Comment: Pretty sure... are you talking about external or internal screws? The wobble is a few millimeters but still annoying. Obviously the deep ones must go in the correct slots but it's possible I mixed up the short ones.

Comment: It would be a pity to incur the cost of shipping it back if all they decide is you voided the warranty and didn't tighten the screws properly.

Comment: I suggest you try opening it again and making sure everything you touched it back on tight

Comment: Pretty sure that it doesn't void the warranty... see comments here http://osxdaily.com/2010/05/19/install-an-ssd-into-the-optical-drive-slot-on-a-macbook-pro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you over-tightened a screw, or tightened them unevenly - ie, tightened one all the way before tightening the others.

Try loosening them a bit and seeing if the wobble disappears. If it does, just make sure to tighten them evenly without over doing it.